# How to add string parameter to a freestyle jenkins job via groovy?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, hudson

I am new to Groovy and trying to add a *string parameter*  to a *Jenkins job* via Groovy (not using plugins)

I found similar set of examples for *Workflow* job and not for `FreeStyleProject`

https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=hudson.model.FreeStyleProject

If anyone could help me it would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching for days, the following solution worked

```
ParameterDefinition paramDef = new StringParameterDefinition("CUSTOM_BUILD_PARAM", "Test", "");
ParametersDefinitionProperty paramsDef = new ParametersDefinitionProperty(paramDef);

job.addProperty(paramsDef);
```

where 'job' is of type 'FreeStyleProject'

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String Parameter Definition](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/StringParameterDefinition.html)

It accepts 3 parameters

```
new StringParameterDefinition(parameterName, defaultValue, description)
```

Also, be sure to import it!

```
import hudson.model.*
```